# Image color-moment extractor

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, numpy, opencv

I was just wondering if there is a way to speed up the performances of this for loops in Python.

I'm trying to process an image to get the color-moments **without using libraries**. 
It takes about 12sec to do the *calculate_mean* and *calculate_standard_deviation* functions for each part of the image.

```
import math

import cv2
import numpy as np
```

```
parts = 2
new_height = int(img.shape[0]/parts)
new_width = int(img.shape[1]/parts)

for i in range (0,img.shape[0],new_height):
    for j in range(0,img.shape[1],new_width):
        color_moments = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        cropped_image = img[i:i+new_height,j:j+new_width]
        yuv_image = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
        Y,U,V = cv2.split(yuv_image)

        pixel_image_y = np.array(Y).flatten()
        pixel_image_u = np.array(U).flatten()
        pixel_image_v = np.array(V).flatten()

        calculate_mean(pixel_image_y,pixel_image_u,pixel_image_v,color_moments)
        calculate_standard_deviation(pixel_image_y, pixel_image_u, pixel_image_v, color_moments)
```

And this are the two functions:

```
def calculate_mean(pixel_image_y,pixel_image_u,pixel_image_v,color_moments):
    for p in pixel_image_y:
        color_moments[0]+=(1/(new_height*new_width))*int(p)
    for p in pixel_image_u:
        color_moments[1]+=(1/(new_height*new_width))*int(p)
    for p in pixel_image_v:
        color_moments[2]+=(1/(new_height*new_width))*int(p)

def calculate_standard_deviation(pixel_image_y,pixel_image_u,pixel_image_v,color_moments):
    temp = [0,0,0]
    for p in pixel_image_y:
        temp[0]+=(p-color_moments[0])**2
    color_moments[3] = math.sqrt((1/(new_height*new_width))*temp[0])
    for p in pixel_image_u:
        temp[1]+=(p-color_moments[1])**2
    color_moments[4] = math.sqrt((1/(new_height*new_width))*temp[1])
    for p in pixel_image_v:
        temp[2]+=(p-color_moments[2])**2
    color_moments[5] = math.sqrt((1/(new_height*new_width))*temp[2])
```

Comment: is `color_moments` reset for each iteration, because that is not clear from the code here. Why not just use [`np.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [`np.std`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)

Comment: Yes, color_moments is reset for each iteration. I'm trying to not use the libraries

Comment: Bolding "without using libraries" seems really odd. Like really really really odd, since you're using numpy and opencv. Please explain why you don't want to use these libraries and which libraries you can use. Because currently your description says one thing and your code says another.

Comment: I need to calculate the mean and standard deviation without the libraries given by numpy. I edited the code to show how I reset the color_moments

Comment: So, if the color moments are reset every iteration and you don't do anything with them, not even displaying, why calculate them in the first place?

Comment: Please add your imports and all other relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Python 2 is end of life, many core libraries and tools are dropping Python 2 support.
2. Python is dumb. If you tell it to calculate `(1/(new_height*new_width)` each and every loop, then Python will.
3. Your style is not Pythonic, you should have more whitespace.
4. If we change one of the for loops in `calculate_mean` to math, we can see we can that ¶2 isn't needed inside the loop.

   ```py
   for p in pixel_image_y:
       color_moments[0]+=(1/(new_height*new_width))*int(p)
   ```

   $$
   \Sigma \frac{\lfloor p \rfloor}{hw} = \frac{\Sigma \lfloor p \rfloor}{hw}
   $$
5. We can utilize numpy to perform the loop, in `calculate_standard_deviation`, in C.

   ```py
   color_moments[3] = (
       np.sum((pixel_image_y - color_moments[0]) ** 2)
       * math.sqrt((1/(new_height*new_width))
   )
   ```
6. You should change `calculate_mean` and `calculate_standard_deviation` to either work in one dimension or all dimensions.
7. You should remove `color_moments` from your code. You should `return` if you need to return.
8. You can determine `new_height*new_width` by the values you enter in your function. No need to pass them.

```py
def mean(values):
    return sum(int(v) for v in values) / len(values)

def std_deviation(values):
    return np.sum((values - mean(values)) ** 2) / math.sqrt(len(values))
```

Comment: I don't understand the fourth point

Comment: @EnricoMosca If we have the list `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` then this can be seen as \$\Sigma \frac{\lfloor p \rfloor}{5} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{0}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{0}{5} + \frac{1}{5}\$, we can simplify this to move the fraction away from the sum \$\frac{\Sigma \lfloor p \rfloor}{5} = \frac{1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1}{5}\$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help!!